# Can't use pivot_wider after grouping with COUNT

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, plyr

Today, I used the `count()` with  `group_by()` and `summarise()` from the dplyr package. Here is the code:

```
dplyr::group_by(QUARTER, PROVINCE, DATE) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(COUNT = count(EDUCATION)) %>%
ungroup()
```

Here is what my `df` looks like after executing the code above:

```
Quarter    PROVINCE      DATE        COUNT.x        COUNT.freq

2020Q1   New-York       2020-01-07     1              30
2021Q1   New-York       2020-01-07     2              21
2020Q1   New-York       2020-01-07     3              55
2021Q1   New-York       2020-01-07     4              8
```

Note: I did not create `COUNT.x` and `COUNT.freq` myself! Now, I am trying to take the `COUNT.x` as columns and `COUNT.freq` as the values. This means `pivot_wider()` would be the solution here. However, after trying the following:

```
pivot_wider(df, names_from = COUNT.x, values_from = COUNT.freq)
```

It says `COUNT.x` and `COUNT.freq` do not exist:

```
Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Column `COUNT.x` doesn't exist
```

Also, checking `names(df) gives me:

```
[1] "QUARTER"  "PROVINCE" "DATE" "COUNT"
```

It does not include `COUNT.x` and `COUNT.freq`!

Any has a solution to this problem?

Comment: Is the dataset you show the one you want to pivot or the one you are making counts with? If it is the latter, can you add a small example of your original dataset and the whole pipeline that creates the counts that you then want to pivot? That way folks can first see if they can reproduce the problem with `pivot_wider()` and, if so, offer solutions.  One way to add a small dataset is to copy the output of `dput(head(datasetname))`.

Answer (score 1):

Is your `pivot_wider` call referencing a dataframe through a pipe?
It doesn't currently look like it.

Try

```
pivot_wider(df, names_from = COUNT.x, values_from = COUNT.freq)
```

where df is the name of your dataframe.

If that doesn't work can you supplt the dput of your dataframe so we can understand the names? maybe there is a space etc

EDIT

```
structure(
  list(
    Quarter = c("2020Q1", "2021Q1", "2020Q1", "2021Q1"), 
    PROVINCE = c("New-York", "New-York", "New-York", "New-York"),
    DATE = c("07/01/2020", "07/01/2020", "07/01/2020", "07/01/2020"),
    COUNT.x = 1:4, 
    COUNT.freq = c(30L, 21L, 55L, 8L)
    ), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-4L)
  ) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = COUNT.x, values_from = COUNT.freq)
```

Comment: Okay, in which case we need to see your input data then.


I've added an edit so you can see that your `pivot_wider` does work.

Comment: Problem is. When I check the column names of the dataframe it says COUNT.x does not exist. It only shows COUNT without the x and freq.